# Referencing cell value of a query formula in Google Sheets via apps script does not appear to work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing, google-sheets-query

I am attempting to copy the value of a cell to another cell using Apps Script. Source cell's value is produced by a query formula:

```
=sum(iferror(query(ExportDrop!$A$2:$AJ,"select AJ where A matches '" & join("|",C$3:C) & "' AND AH = '" & A3 & "'",0),0))
```

Source sheet displays the output of this query formula successfully and correctly.

Working within a script, the following code produces a zero (0), which is different than when viewing the sheet.

```
cellval = sourceSheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(cellval); return;
```

I have attempted getDisplayValue(), getValue(), getValues() (with corresponding change to the range reference), using setActiveRangeSelection(), copyValuesToRange(), copyTo(,{contentsOnly: true}) etc.

**Is this a bug in Google Sheet's query function?** I wonder because the same thing occurs when I print to PDF the source sheet containing a query function. The resulting PDF shows zero-values. So it appears not to be an issue with my script, but more like an issue with the source sheet. Tests of a "simpler" query-formula sheet printed work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eHHV-TJhC_aVNNLspx3suKhrthtcjRfIcZR0dWdTvOI

Try printing Sheet2. The first PDF "preview" looks good, but upon opening the PDF after export, the sum values are all zeros.

Comment: Need a sample sheet link to demonstrate.

Comment: @CodeCamper My apologies, should have included that in the OP. I've edited it to include.

Comment: Added the link, and ensured it is showing the bug.

Comment: I don't see any glitch, in Sheet 2 column B is all zeroes whether I print or not.

Comment: @CodeCamper Wow that is **not** what I see. I see this: https://imgur.com/a/hsidqEN  and those numbers are, in fact, correct, per the source data.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your web browser, if so, try updating your google chrome/delete cache/cookies.

Comment: The situation gets stranger. Using a fresh Brave Browser window, the sheet originally showed zeros as you suggested. After touching the formulas in column B via Chrome, my Brave window showed the correct values. Opening a fresh Brave browser results in the zero values again. So it looks like a bug, but not related to my issue.
It looks like the browser is rendering zeros when it first loads the sheet, but if the sheet is updated while the browser is open, it shows the correct values.

Comment: I have enabled that test sheet for editing. You can recreate my issue by click-dragging cell B1 down to B13 to refresh the values, then it will produce the issue describe. So it appears that there is a more insidious bug.

Comment: Your `matches` portion of the query search seems to be causing the glitch.

Comment: Try `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before getValue

Comment: @TheMaster it appears `matches` is not running on the server at all and only locally sort of like how the `format` boolean feature is just false advertising on google's part. A simple web browser refresh sadly demonstrates this desync glitch.

Comment: @Code I haven't tested, but even if that's the case(which most probably is), `flush` is still worth a shot.

Comment: @TheMaster it would be interesting if `flush` causes it to register in GAS but then there is still the issue that when you hit print it shows you in the preview but the final print it reverts back to the server value of 0.

Comment: @Nat `copyValuesToRange` Did it work?

Comment: @Code if `flush` fixes the sync, wouldn't the pdf export be fixed as well?

Comment: @TheMaster I tried the `flush` it still displays zero even though it is 10 right in your face, the `matches` is just not making it to the server at all, refreshing brings everything back to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: Google Sheets Query function has advertised features that are broken/incomplete.

Example: `matches` run's locally and never on the google server causing desync issue, `format` boolean does not work at all.

Work around: Use a series of `OR` in lieu of the `matches`

```
=sum(iferror(query(Sheet1!$A$2:C,"select C where (A = " &join(" OR A = ",filter(C$1:C,C$1:C<>"")) & ") AND B = '" & A1 & "'",0),0))
```

Comment: Alas. Do you know of an alternative to "matches" to produce a "where in" type of query? I suppose I may need to build a sequence of ORs.

Comment: @NatWest Obviously that is what most people do, I use tons of Query's and never have these kind of issues probably because I make sure to never use `matches`

Comment: @NatWest Consider creating a issue in the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)